# Can't link assembly file in Mac OS X using ld

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, ld, object-files

I'm trying to run a basic assembly file using 64 Bit Mac OS X Lion, using nasm and ld which are installed by default with Xcode.

I've written an assembly file, which prints a character, and I got it to build using nasm.

`nasm -f elf -o program.o main.asm`

However, when I go to link it with ld, it fails with quite a few errors/warnings:

`ld -o program program.o`

```
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specificed, assuming 10.7
ld: warning: ignoring file program.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found, normally in libSystem.dylib
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for inferred architecture x86_64
```

So, I tried to rectify a few of these issues, and got nowhere.

Here's one of things I've tried:

`ld -arch i386 -e _start -o program program.o`

Which I thought would work, but I was wrong.

How do you make the object file a compatible architecture that nasm and ld will agree with?

Also, how would you define the entry point in the program (right now I'm using `global _start` in `.section text`, which is above `_start`, which doesn't seem to do much good.)

I'm a bit confused as to how you would successfully link an object file to a binary file using ld, and I think I'm just missing some code (or argument to nasm or ld) that will make them agree.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried linking using gcc instead of ld? It's often a lot easier and you can use the C runtime and standard library (e.g. have `main` as the entry point). Another thing to try is to use a `mach` object file format instead of `elf`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `global start` and `start:`, **no underscore**. Also, you should not be using `elf` as the arch. Here is a bash script I use to assemble my x86-64 NASM programs on Mac OS X:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "$1" && -f "$1" ]]; then
    filename="$1"
    base="${filename%%.*}"
    ext="${filename##*.}"

    nasm -f macho64 -Ox "$filename" \
    && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7 "${base}.o" -o "$base"
fi
```

If you have a file called `foo.s`, this script will first run

```
nasm -f macho64 -Ox foo.s
```

Which will create `foo.o`. The `-Ox` flag makes NASM do some extra optimization with jumps (i.e. making them short, near or far) so that you don't have to do it yourself. I'm using x86-64, so my code is 64-bit, but it looks like you're trying to assemble 32-bit. In that case, you would use `-f macho32`. See `nasm -hf` for a list of valid output formats.

Now, the object file will be linked:

```
ld -macosx_version_min 10.7 foo.o -o foo
```

I've set the `-macosx_version_min` option to quiet NASM down and prevent a warning. You don't have to set it to Lion (10.7). This will create an executable called `foo`. With any luck, typing `./foo` and hitting return should run your program.

In regard to the `ld: warning: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found, normally in libSystem.dylib` warning, I get that every time too and I'm not sure why, but everything seems fine when I run the executable.

Answer (score 5):

OK, looking at your samples I assume you either used a generic nasm or linux assembly tutorial.
The first thing you need to take care of is the binary format created by nasm.
Your post states:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file program.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

Thats the result of the *'**-f elf**'* parameter which tells nasm you want a 32bit ELF object (which would be the case for e.g. linux). But since you're on OSX what you want is a Mach-O object.

Try the following:

```
nasm -f macho64 -o program.o main.asm
gcc -o program program.o
```

Or if you wan't to create a 32bit binary:

```
nasm -f macho32 -o program.o main.asm
gcc -m32 -o program program.o
```

---

Regarding the **_start** symbol - if you wan't to create a simple program that will be able
to use the provided libc system functions then you shouldn't use **_start** at al.
It's the default entry point *ld* will look for and normaly it's provided in your libc / libsystem.

I suggest you try to replace the **_start** in your code by something like **'_main'**
and link it like the example above states.

A generic libc-based assembly template for nasm could look like this:

```
;---------------------------------------------------
.section text
;---------------------------------------------------
use32             ; use64 if you create 64bit code
global _main      ; export the symbol so ld can find it

_main:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp ; create a basic stack frame

    [your code here]

    pop ebp       ; restore original stack
    mov eax, 0    ; store the return code for main in eax
    ret           ; exit the program
```

---

In addition to this I should mention that any **call**'s you do on OSX need to use an aligned stack frame or your code will just crash.
There are some good tutorials on that out there too - try searching for OSX assembly guide.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier just to let `gcc` do the heavy lifting for you, rather than trying to drive `ld` directly, e.g.

```
$ gcc -m32 program.o -o program
```

Answer (score 1):

The mac gcc compiler won't link elf objects. You need a cross compiler...

http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_linux

Then you can proceed with something similar to this...

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```